# Wrapping small images inside a svg map

Tags: jquery, css, html, svg

I am facing a weird challenge. My challenge is to fit more than 700 small images inside a svg map path. I have tried many different ideas but failing every time.

My target:

[image]

What I am doing:

```css
.big-map {
    background: url(img/map.svg) no-repeat;
    height: 360px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
  .map-flex {
    background: rgba(200, 20, 20, 0.5);
    height: 149px;
    width: 333px;
    transform: rotateZ(23deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 64px;
    transform-origin: left top;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .big-map img {
    width: 16px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="big-map">
  <div class="map-flex">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
    <img src="img/a.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

My map.svg contains:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="-191 305.6 389.5 182.4" style="enable-background:new -191 305.6 389.5 182.4;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#231F20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g class="group">
<path class="st0" d="M196.6,473.1c-0.3,0-0.6,0.1-0.8,0.1c0.2,5.1-0.2,8-3,11.2c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.8,0.3c-1.6-1-2.9-2.2-4.8-3.1
 c0-0.7-0.5-1.7-1.3-2.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.4c-1.2,0.7-0.7,1.6-2.2,2.1c-0.8-0.6-1-1.1-2.2-1.3c-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.9-0.7,3
 c-1.9,0-2.2-0.6-4.2-0.7c0,1.8-2.1,2.8-4.1,3c-3-3.4-9.7-2.8-10.4,2.5c-2,0.2-2.4-0.4-4.3-0.4c-0.2-1.2-0.5-1.5-1.1-2.1
 c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0c-1.3,0.5-2.9,1-4.7,0.8c-2.9-1.6-4-4.5-4.5-8.9c-1.4,0.5-1.1,2.4-2.2,3.3c-1.2,0.4-2.4,0.7-3.6,1.1
 c0,0.4,0,0.8,0,1.2c-0.4,0-0.9,0.1-1.3,0.1c0,0.8-0.1,1.3-0.5,1.8c-1.8,1.2-3.2,1.4-5.4,0.8c-0.4,1.2-0.6,1.8-2.3,2
 c-0.9-1.8-5-2.2-6.9-2.8c-0.6-0.7-1.3-1.4-1.9-2.2c-0.7,0-1.4-0.1-2.1-0.1c-2.5-0.7-5.4-2.1-7.6-3.1c-1.3,0.2-2.6,0.4-3.8,0.6
 c-0.3,0.9-0.4,1.2-1.7,1.4c-0.5-0.2-0.8-0.9-1.1-1.1c-0.8,0.1-1.7,0.3-2.5,0.4c-3-1-4.6-3-8.1-1c-0.5,2.2-2.7,3.2-4.1,4.7
 c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.2,0c0-1.2,0.2-1.2-0.4-2c-1.2,0.4-4.6-0.9-5.3-1.8c-1.6-2.3-0.6-5.6-1.4-8.3c-1.6-0.9-3.6-1.6-5.1-2.7
 c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2c-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.5,1.2c-0.8,0-0.7-0.1-1.2-0.4c-0.7,2.5-4.3,4.3-7.2,4.3c-1,1-2.1,1.9-3.1,2.9
 c-2.1,0-3.8-0.6-6.5-0.3c-1-2.1-1-2.8-1.3-5.5c-3.5,0.4-4.2,1.4-7.3,1.8c0-0.6,0-1.1,0-1.7c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.8-0.3
 c-0.8,0-1.6-0.1-2.4-0.1c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1c-0.5,0.1-1,0.1-1.5,0.2c0-0.2,0-0.3-0.1-0.5c0.1-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.2-1.2
 c-1.4-0.7-3.6-0.3-5.2-1.1c-1-0.5-0.8-1.5-2.2-1.8c-0.3,0.8-0.4,1-1.6,1.2c-0.1-0.1-6-1.6-6.8-1.6c0.2-1.9,1.2-3,1.3-4.9
 c0.3-3.1-0.4-4.8-1.8-6.8c-4.6-7-11.7-1.5-18.5-4.5c-0.2-1.7-0.7-1.8-1.5-2.7c-0.7,0.2-1.3,0.5-2,0.7c-0.1-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.5
 c-1.5,0.1-1.8-0.4-3-0.7c0.1-0.5,0.1-1,0.2-1.5c-1,0.4-1.3,0.5-2.2,0.1c0.1,1.8-1.1,2.9-1.7,4.3c-2.2,0.5-8.5,0.1-9.9,1.6
 c0.8,0.8,1.5,1.5,2.3,2.3c-0.2,0.6-0.3,1.2-0.5,1.8c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1c-5.8-4.1-12.3-4.9-22.1-4.2c0.6,0.9,0.4,1.3-0.1,2.1
 c0.4,0.4,0.8,0.7,1.1,1.1c-0.4,1.7-1.5,3.2-2.4,4.5c-0.9,0.2-1.8,0.3-2.7,0.5c-1.5-2.4-3.6-4.2-5.7-5.8c-3.3,0.3-6.6,0.6-9.9,0.9
 c-1.1-0.2-1.3-1.4-2.2-1.8c-2.1-0.5-6.5,1.7-8,0.3c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.3c-1.1-1.8-0.4-3.1-0.8-4.2c-1-2.6-2.1-3.5-2.7-6.2
 c-3.1,0.8-9.4,3.7-12.4,3c-1.7-0.4-2.5-2.1-3.9-2.8c-2.7-1.5-5.5-3.2-8.1-4.4c-1.2-0.6-2.6,0.1-3.8-0.6c-0.9-0.9-1.9-1.8-2.8-2.8
 c-1.4,0.1-2.8,0.2-4.2,0.3c-0.6,1.3-1.2,2.6-1.8,3.9c-0.6,0-1.2,0-1.9,0c-3.3-1.1-6.8-4.9-9.3-5.8c-0.9,0-1.8,0.1-2.7,0.1
 c-1.6-0.9-3.3-1.8-4.9-2.7c-1-0.2-2.1-0.5-3.1-0.7c-0.1-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.3-2.4c-1.2-0.5-1.5-1.9-2.6-2.3c-0.9,0-1.8,0.1-2.7,0.1
 c-2.1-0.2-4-1.6-5.2-2.8c-1.4-1.5-2.1-5.8-4.1-6.5c-1.1,0-2.2,0-3.2,0c-1.9-0.3-2.9-0.9-4.6-0.3c-0.5-1.3-0.6-1.8-1.2-2.9
 c-0.6,0.5-0.7,0.9-1.7,1.2c-0.6-1-1.8-1.2-3.2-1.2c-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.4-0.6-2c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9-0.2c-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8-1.6,1
 c-0.6-0.8-1.6-1.5-2.9-1.6c-0.2-0.9,0-0.7-0.6-1c-0.8-1.4-2-1-3.7-1.1c-0.6-1.5-1.3-1.7-1.9-3c-1.8,0.3-2.7,0-3.8-0.4
 c-0.2-0.5-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.6c-0.5,0-1,0-1.5,0c-0.5,0.5-1,0.9-1.6,1.4c0.4,1.7,1.9,4.3,1.4,5.5c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3
 c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1c-1.2-1.3-2.4-2.4-3.6-3.9c-1.2,0.2-2.6,0.9-3.5,0.4c-1.2-0.5-2.5-1.4-2.7-3.1c-0.8-0.1-1.6-0.2-2.4-0.2
 c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c0.1-0.7,0.2-0.8,0-1.5c-4.1,0.5-4.2-2.2-6.8-3c-0.9-0.3-1.9,0.2-2.6-0.1c-1.4-4-0.8-6.6,1.8-8.5
 c0.1-1.6-0.5-4.3,0.2-6.1c0.3-0.8,1.1-0.9,1.3-2c0.9,0.2,1.9,0.5,2.8,0.7c0.3-0.6,0.6-0.9,1.4-1.2c-0.7-1.2-1.4-2.4-1.6-4.1
 c1.1,0,1.6,0.4,2.3,0.9c0-2,0.4-4,0.5-6c-1.9-0.5-2.3-1.7-2.5-3.8c-0.8-0.1-1.4-0.4-1.8-1c0.4-0.6,0.1-1.4,0.6-1.9
 c0.8-0.6,0.8-0.5,1.8-0.4c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.6-1c1-1,1.9-2,2.9-3c-0.4-0.6-0.5-0.5-0.5-1.3
 c2.1-1.1,3.1-2.9,2.6-5.4c-0.9-0.1-3.7-3.2-2.7-5c0.1-0.3,2.5-3,3.2-3.4c0.8,0.1,1.6,0.2,2.4,0.2c0.5-1.6,1.7-1.7,2.6-2.8
 c1.4-1.8-0.1-4.8,1.9-6.1c1.1-0.7,1.5-0.1,3-0.2c1-1.7,2.7-2.1,3.4-3.3c0.9-1.6,0.7-3.5,2.2-4.7c1.1-0.8,2.4-1.1,2.8-2.3
 c-0.3-0.6-0.6-1.2-0.9-1.8c0.9-0.6,1.3-1.8,1.7-2.7c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.2c0.1,0.7,0.1,0.8,0.5,1.1c2,0.7,4.4-2,6.5-1
 c0.7,0.8,1.3,1.6,2,2.3c-0.1,1-0.8,2.1-0.2,3.2c0.6,0.8,1.4,0.5,2.3,0.9c4,1.9,6.2,1.1,4.9-4.8c1.1-0.4,3-0.5,3.9-1.3
 c0.5-1.9,1.9-4.7,2.1-7c0.1-1.2-1-1.9-1.3-2.6c-1.7-3.6,1.4-4.4,4.4-4.7c1.2,1.5,2,2.2,4.3,2.3c-0.3-1.5-0.5-2.4,0.3-3.3
 c0.7,0.1,1.2-0.5,2.4-0.3c1.8,0.7,3.5,1.3,5.3,2c3.9,0.8,7.7,0.3,11,1.2c2.5,0.7,6.3-1.5,8.3,0.1c-0.4,5.9,1.8,3.7,3.1,7
 c0.9,2.1-0.8,3.3-0.2,4.6c3.7,0.4,7.7,1.9,11.2,2.9c1.5,0.4,2.6-0.2,3.6,0.3c0.7,1.5,3.7,1.4,4.9,2.9c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.5,1.3
 c1.8,1.3,3.7,2.7,5.5,4c0.9,1,1.2,2.9,2.4,3.5c0.9,0.1,1.8,0.3,2.8,0.4c0.5,0.5,0.9,1,1.4,1.6c1.1-0.1,2.1-0.2,3.2-0.3
 c2.7,0.6,5.5,2.4,8,3.2c1.1-0.1,2.1-0.1,3.2-0.2c0.2,0.4,0.4,0.7,0.6,1.1c1.5,0.9,3.2-0.7,4.6,1.2c0.1,0.8,0.3,1.7,0.4,2.5
 c1.3,0.3,2.9,0.1,3.7,1.1c0.4,0.8,0,1.4,0.4,2c1,0.6,2,1.3,2.9,1.9c1.4,1.6,1.7,4.5,3,6.1c0.6,0.2,1.2,0.3,1.8,0.5
 c2.1,1.1,4.5,6.2,7.9,4.2c0.3-1.5,2.2-4.1,4.3-4c0.8,0,1.6,0.1,2.4,0.1c0.9-0.4,0.8-1.6,1.3-2.3c1.4-2.2,6-2.6,8.3-2.3
 c0,0.4,0.1,0.9,0.1,1.3c0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7,0.3c2.3-1.9,3.9,0.6,5.8,1.4c1.2,0.5,2-0.3,2.8,0.7c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1
 c-0.2,1-1,1-1.2,1.8c0.1,1.5,0.1,3,0.2,4.6c-0.6,0.9-1.2,1.8-1.7,2.7c0.9,0.9,1.8,1.7,2.7,2.6c0.1,1.7-1.3,4.2-0.3,5.5
 c1.9-0.6,3.5-1.8,5.6-2c1.1,2.6,5.5,1.9,7.9,3.9c0.2,1.9-0.2,2.7-0.4,4.3c1.8-0.9,2.3,0.5,4.1,0.6c4,0.2,4-2.7,8.1-0.7
 c0.5,2.7,1.5,2.2,1.3,5.3c2.3-0.1,6.1,0.3,7.8,1.2c2.5-1.8,2.8-2.2,6.2-2.2c1.2-2.3,2.5-4.3,6.1-4.7c1.1,1,2.1,1.9,3.2,2.9
 c-0.1,3.3-1,6.2-1.7,9.2c-0.2,1.9-0.4,3.9-0.6,5.8c1.5,0.9,2.9-0.3,4.3-0.8c0.8,0.9,1.6,1.9,2.3,2.8c1.4-0.4,2.9-0.9,4.3-1.3
 c0.5,0.1,0.8,0.6,1.8,0.7c4.1-7.5,12.6,0.7,16.8,2.6c0.5-0.3,1.1-0.6,1.6-0.9c2.3,1.6,4.5,3.1,6.8,4.7c0.6,1.4,1.2,2.8,1.8,4.2
 c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.4,1.9,2.2c0.5,1.3-0.4,1.6-0.1,2.4c2.6,0.1,5.5,1.7,7.2-1c-1.4-2.8-3.1-3.9-2.9-8.3c2-0.9,2.5-3.7,4.3-3.9
 c0.7,1.6,1.4,2.2,2.2,3.3c-0.4,1.6-0.6,2.1,0.1,4.1c1.2,3.4,2.7,0.9,5.6,1.8c0.9,0.3,0.7,1.1,1.8,1.3c0.9-0.7,2.7-2.3,3.3-0.5
 c-0.7,0.8-1.1,1.2-0.6,2.1c2.9-0.9,1.4-1.7,4.8-1c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7c-0.6-0.7-1.2-1.3-1.7-2c0.1-2,2.2-5.2,3.6-6
 c2.2-0.6,2.4,0.2,3.9-1.6c1.4-0.2,2.1-0.3,3.2,0c0.1,1,0.4,2.1,1,2.6c0.6,0.4,1.8,0.9,2.7,1.4c0.7-0.4,1-0.7,2.1-0.9
 c1.3,1,3.7,3.4,5.5,3.5c0.9-0.2,1.9-0.3,2.8-0.5c1.2,0.3,5.2,3.4,6.4,4.2c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.2-0.7,1.8c1.6-0.1,3.2-0.1,4.7-0.2
 c0.7-0.4,0.7-1.5,2.2-1.4c1,0.1,2,0.2,2.9,0.4c1.2-0.4,1.9-1.7,3.8-1.4c0.1,0.8,0,0.9,0.3,1.2c2.5,0.7,4.6-2.4,6.8-2.9
 c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1c0.1,1.3,0.2,2.3,1,2.8c1.2-0.9,4.6-3.8,5.3-0.9c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.2-1.2c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.8,2.1,1
 c0.1-0.8,0.2-1,0.7-1.4c1.3,0.2,2.1,0.1,2.7,1.2c0.8-0.3,1.6-0.5,2.5-0.8c0.6-2.2,1.4-4,3-5.4c2.8-0.2,2.8,1.1,4.5,1.9
 c1.1,0.2,1.6-0.1,2.1-0.7c1.1,0.5,2.1,0.9,3.2,1.4c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.1,0.8c-0.3,0.3-0.6,0.6-0.9,0.9c0.3,0.6,0.6,1.3,0.9,1.9
 c-0.9,0.7-4.7,14-5.4,15.9c0.8,1,1.4,1.6,1.6,3.4c-1.1,0.6-0.9,1.4-1.1,2.7c0.6,0.5,0.9,0.7,1.2,1.7c-1.6,3.5-1.7,8-2.1,11.8
 c1.4,0.9,0.9,1.7,2,3c0.7,0.9,1.9,0.1,2.8,0.7c1.1,0.7,1,1.6,2.4,2.1c-0.1,2.6,1.1,3.7,2.6,5.5c0.2,0.3,1.2,4.1,1.4,4.8
 C199.4,466.2,196.3,469.3,196.6,473.1z"></path></g>
</svg>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:**

As Paul LeBeau have mentioned in the answer, I have tried the following:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.scale(1.8453456, 2.0702263);
var p = new Path2D("m 390,170 c -0.3,0 -0.6,0.1 -0.8,0.1 0.2,5.1 -0.2,8 -3,11.2 -0.3,0.1 -0.5,0.2 -0.8,0.3 -1.6,-1 -2.9,-2.2 -4.8,-3.1 0,-0.7 -0.5,-1.7 -1.3,-2.4 -0.1,0.1 -0.2,0.2 -0.3,0.4 -1.2,0.7 -0.7,1.6 -2.2,2.1 -0.8,-0.6 -1,-1.1 -2.2,-1.3 -0.2,1.1 -0.4,1.9 -0.7,3 -1.9,0 -2.2,-0.6 -4.2,-0.7 0,1.8 -2.1,2.8 -4.1,3 -3,-3.4 -9.7,-2.8 -10.4,2.5 -2,0.2 -2.4,-0.4 -4.3,-0.4 -0.2,-1.2 -0.5,-1.5 -1.1,-2.1 -0.1,0 -0.1,0 -0.2,0 -1.3,0.5 -2.9,1 -4.7,0.8 -2.9,-1.6 -4,-4.5 -4.5,-8.9 -1.4,0.5 -1.1,2.4 -2.2,3.3 -1.2,0.4 -2.4,0.7 -3.6,1.1 0,0.4 0,0.8 0,1.2 -0.4,0 -0.9,0.1 -1.3,0.1 0,0.8 -0.1,1.3 -0.5,1.8 -1.8,1.2 -3.2,1.4 -5.4,0.8 -0.4,1.2 -0.6,1.8 -2.3,2 -0.9,-1.8 -5,-2.2 -6.9,-2.8 -0.6,-0.7 -1.3,-1.4 -1.9,-2.2 -0.7,0 -1.4,-0.1 -2.1,-0.1 -2.5,-0.7 -5.4,-2.1 -7.6,-3.1 -1.3,0.2 -2.6,0.4 -3.8,0.6 -0.3,0.9 -0.4,1.2 -1.7,1.4 -0.5,-0.2 -0.8,-0.9 -1.1,-1.1 -0.8,0.1 -1.7,0.3 -2.5,0.4 -3,-1 -4.6,-3 -8.1,-1 -0.5,2.2 -2.7,3.2 -4.1,4.7 -0.4,0 -0.8,0 -1.2,0 0,-1.2 0.2,-1.2 -0.4,-2 -1.2,0.4 -4.6,-0.9 -5.3,-1.8 -1.6,-2.3 -0.6,-5.6 -1.4,-8.3 -1.6,-0.9 -3.6,-1.6 -5.1,-2.7 -0.1,0.1 -0.2,0.1 -0.3,0.2 -0.2,0.4 -0.4,0.8 -0.5,1.2 -0.8,0 -0.7,-0.1 -1.2,-0.4 -0.7,2.5 -4.3,4.3 -7.2,4.3 -1,1 -2.1,1.9 -3.1,2.9 -2.1,0 -3.8,-0.6 -6.5,-0.3 -1,-2.1 -1,-2.8 -1.3,-5.5 -3.5,0.4 -4.2,1.4 -7.3,1.8 0,-0.6 0,-1.1 0,-1.7 0.3,-0.1 0.5,-0.2 0.8,-0.3 -0.8,0 -1.6,-0.1 -2.4,-0.1 0,-0.3 -0.1,-0.7 -0.1,-1 -0.5,0.1 -1,0.1 -1.5,0.2 0,-0.2 0,-0.3 -0.1,-0.5 0.1,-0.4 0.1,-0.8 0.2,-1.2 -1.4,-0.7 -3.6,-0.3 -5.2,-1.1 -1,-0.5 -0.8,-1.5 -2.2,-1.8 -0.3,0.8 -0.4,1 -1.6,1.2 -0.1,-0.1 -6,-1.6 -6.8,-1.6 0.2,-1.9 1.2,-3 1.3,-4.9 0.3,-3.1 -0.4,-4.8 -1.8,-6.8 -4.6,-7 -11.7,-1.5 -18.5,-4.5 -0.2,-1.7 -0.7,-1.8 -1.5,-2.7 -0.7,0.2 -1.3,0.5 -2,0.7 -0.1,-0.5 -0.1,-1 -0.2,-1.5 -1.5,0.1 -1.8,-0.4 -3,-0.7 0.1,-0.5 0.1,-1 0.2,-1.5 -1,0.4 -1.3,0.5 -2.2,0.1 0.1,1.8 -1.1,2.9 -1.7,4.3 -2.2,0.5 -8.5,0.1 -9.9,1.6 0.8,0.8 1.5,1.5 2.3,2.3 -0.2,0.6 -0.3,1.2 -0.5,1.8 -0.2,0 -0.4,0 -0.7,0.1 -5.8,-4.1 -12.3,-4.9 -22.1,-4.2 0.6,0.9 0.4,1.3 -0.1,2.1 0.4,0.4 0.8,0.7 1.1,1.1 -0.4,1.7 -1.5,3.2 -2.4,4.5 -0.9,0.2 -1.8,0.3 -2.7,0.5 -1.5,-2.4 -3.6,-4.2 -5.7,-5.8 -3.3,0.3 -6.6,0.6 -9.9,0.9 -1.1,-0.2 -1.3,-1.4 -2.2,-1.8 -2.1,-0.5 -6.5,1.7 -8,0.3 0,-0.1 0,-0.2 0,-0.3 -1.1,-1.8 -0.4,-3.1 -0.8,-4.2 -1,-2.6 -2.1,-3.5 -2.7,-6.2 -3.1,0.8 -9.4,3.7 -12.4,3 -1.7,-0.4 -2.5,-2.1 -3.9,-2.8 -2.7,-1.5 -5.5,-3.2 -8.1,-4.4 -1.2,-0.6 -2.6,0.1 -3.8,-0.6 -0.9,-0.9 -1.9,-1.8 -2.8,-2.8 -1.4,0.1 -2.8,0.2 -4.2,0.3 -0.6,1.3 -1.2,2.6 -1.8,3.9 -0.6,0 -1.2,0 -1.9,0 -3.3,-1.1 -6.8,-4.9 -9.3,-5.8 -0.9,0 -1.8,0.1 -2.7,0.1 -1.6,-0.9 -3.3,-1.8 -4.9,-2.7 -1,-0.2 -2.1,-0.5 -3.1,-0.7 -0.1,-0.8 -0.2,-1.6 -0.3,-2.4 -1.2,-0.5 -1.5,-1.9 -2.6,-2.3 -0.9,0 -1.8,0.1 -2.7,0.1 -2.1,-0.2 -4,-1.6 -5.2,-2.8 -1.4,-1.5 -2.1,-5.8 -4.1,-6.5 -1.1,0 -2.2,0 -3.2,0 -1.9,-0.3 -2.9,-0.9 -4.6,-0.3 -0.5,-1.3 -0.6,-1.8 -1.2,-2.9 -0.6,0.5 -0.7,0.9 -1.7,1.2 -0.6,-1 -1.8,-1.2 -3.2,-1.2 -0.2,-0.9 -0.3,-1.4 -0.6,-2 -0.3,-0.1 -0.6,-0.2 -0.9,-0.2 -0.5,0.5 -0.6,0.8 -1.6,1 -0.6,-0.8 -1.6,-1.5 -2.9,-1.6 -0.2,-0.9 0,-0.7 -0.6,-1 -0.8,-1.4 -2,-1 -3.7,-1.1 -0.6,-1.5 -1.3,-1.7 -1.9,-3 -1.8,0.3 -2.7,0 -3.8,-0.4 -0.2,-0.5 -0.3,-1.1 -0.5,-1.6 -0.5,0 -1,0 -1.5,0 -0.5,0.5 -1,0.9 -1.6,1.4 0.4,1.7 1.9,4.3 1.4,5.5 0,0.1 0,0.2 0,0.3 -0.2,0 -0.4,0 -0.7,0.1 -1.2,-1.3 -2.4,-2.4 -3.6,-3.9 -1.2,0.2 -2.6,0.9 -3.5,0.4 -1.2,-0.5 -2.5,-1.4 -2.7,-3.1 -0.8,-0.1 -1.6,-0.2 -2.4,-0.2 -0.2,-0.3 -0.4,-0.5 -0.6,-0.8 0.1,-0.7 0.2,-0.8 0,-1.5 -4.1,0.5 -4.2,-2.2 -6.8,-3 -0.9,-0.3 -1.9,0.2 -2.6,-0.1 -1.4,-4 -0.8,-6.6 1.8,-8.5 0.1,-1.6 -0.5,-4.3 0.2,-6.1 0.3,-0.8 1.1,-0.9 1.3,-2 0.9,0.2 1.9,0.5 2.8,0.7 0.3,-0.6 0.6,-0.9 1.4,-1.2 -0.7,-1.2 -1.4,-2.4 -1.6,-4.1 1.1,0 1.6,0.4 2.3,0.9 0,-2 0.4,-4 0.5,-6 -1.9,-0.5 -2.3,-1.7 -2.5,-3.8 -0.8,-0.1 -1.4,-0.4 -1.8,-1 0.4,-0.6 0.1,-1.4 0.6,-1.9 0.8,-0.6 0.8,-0.5 1.8,-0.4 0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0,-0.2 -0.2,-0.3 -0.4,-0.6 -0.6,-1 1,-1 1.9,-2 2.9,-3 -0.4,-0.6 -0.5,-0.5 -0.5,-1.3 2.1,-1.1 3.1,-2.9 2.6,-5.4 -0.9,-0.1 -3.7,-3.2 -2.7,-5 0.1,-0.3 2.5,-3 3.2,-3.4 0.8,0.1 1.6,0.2 2.4,0.2 0.5,-1.6 1.7,-1.7 2.6,-2.8 1.4,-1.8 -0.1,-4.8 1.9,-6.1 1.1,-0.7 1.5,-0.1 3,-0.2 1,-1.7 2.7,-2.1 3.4,-3.3 0.9,-1.6 0.7,-3.5 2.2,-4.7 1.1,-0.8 2.4,-1.1 2.8,-2.3 -0.3,-0.6 -0.6,-1.2 -0.9,-1.8 0.9,-0.6 1.3,-1.8 1.7,-2.7 0.3,0.1 0.7,0.2 1,0.2 0.1,0.7 0.1,0.8 0.5,1.1 2,0.7 4.4,-2 6.5,-1 0.7,0.8 1.3,1.6 2,2.3 -0.1,1 -0.8,2.1 -0.2,3.2 0.6,0.8 1.4,0.5 2.3,0.9 4,1.9 6.2,1.1 4.9,-4.8 1.1,-0.4 3,-0.5 3.9,-1.3 0.5,-1.9 1.9,-4.7 2.1,-7 0.1,-1.2 -1,-1.9 -1.3,-2.6 -1.7,-3.6 1.4,-4.4 4.4,-4.7 1.2,1.5 2,2.2 4.3,2.3 -0.3,-1.5 -0.5,-2.4 0.3,-3.3 0.7,0.1 1.2,-0.5 2.4,-0.3 1.8,0.7 3.5,1.3 5.3,2 3.9,0.8 7.7,0.3 11,1.2 2.5,0.7 6.3,-1.5 8.3,0.1 -0.4,5.9 1.8,3.7 3.1,7 0.9,2.1 -0.8,3.3 -0.2,4.6 3.7,0.4 7.7,1.9 11.2,2.9 1.5,0.4 2.6,-0.2 3.6,0.3 0.7,1.5 3.7,1.4 4.9,2.9 0.2,0.4 0.3,0.9 0.5,1.3 1.8,1.3 3.7,2.7 5.5,4 0.9,1 1.2,2.9 2.4,3.5 0.9,0.1 1.8,0.3 2.8,0.4 0.5,0.5 0.9,1 1.4,1.6 1.1,-0.1 2.1,-0.2 3.2,-0.3 2.7,0.6 5.5,2.4 8,3.2 1.1,-0.1 2.1,-0.1 3.2,-0.2 0.2,0.4 0.4,0.7 0.6,1.1 1.5,0.9 3.2,-0.7 4.6,1.2 0.1,0.8 0.3,1.7 0.4,2.5 1.3,0.3 2.9,0.1 3.7,1.1 0.4,0.8 0,1.4 0.4,2 1,0.6 2,1.3 2.9,1.9 1.4,1.6 1.7,4.5 3,6.1 0.6,0.2 1.2,0.3 1.8,0.5 2.1,1.1 4.5,6.2 7.9,4.2 0.3,-1.5 2.2,-4.1 4.3,-4 0.8,0 1.6,0.1 2.4,0.1 0.9,-0.4 0.8,-1.6 1.3,-2.3 1.4,-2.2 6,-2.6 8.3,-2.3 0,0.4 0.1,0.9 0.1,1.3 0.2,0.1 0.5,0.2 0.7,0.3 2.3,-1.9 3.9,0.6 5.8,1.4 1.2,0.5 2,-0.3 2.8,0.7 0.1,0.1 0.1,0.1 0.2,0.1 -0.2,1 -1,1 -1.2,1.8 0.1,1.5 0.1,3 0.2,4.6 -0.6,0.9 -1.2,1.8 -1.7,2.7 0.9,0.9 1.8,1.7 2.7,2.6 0.1,1.7 -1.3,4.2 -0.3,5.5 1.9,-0.6 3.5,-1.8 5.6,-2 1.1,2.6 5.5,1.9 7.9,3.9 0.2,1.9 -0.2,2.7 -0.4,4.3 1.8,-0.9 2.3,0.5 4.1,0.6 4,0.2 4,-2.7 8.1,-0.7 0.5,2.7 1.5,2.2 1.3,5.3 2.3,-0.1 6.1,0.3 7.8,1.2 2.5,-1.8 2.8,-2.2 6.2,-2.2 1.2,-2.3 2.5,-4.3 6.1,-4.7 1.1,1 2.1,1.9 3.2,2.9 -0.1,3.3 -1,6.2 -1.7,9.2 -0.2,1.9 -0.4,3.9 -0.6,5.8 1.5,0.9 2.9,-0.3 4.3,-0.8 0.8,0.9 1.6,1.9 2.3,2.8 1.4,-0.4 2.9,-0.9 4.3,-1.3 0.5,0.1 0.8,0.6 1.8,0.7 4.1,-7.5 12.6,0.7 16.8,2.6 0.5,-0.3 1.1,-0.6 1.6,-0.9 2.3,1.6 4.5,3.1 6.8,4.7 0.6,1.4 1.2,2.8 1.8,4.2 0.6,0.7 1.3,1.4 1.9,2.2 0.5,1.3 -0.4,1.6 -0.1,2.4 2.6,0.1 5.5,1.7 7.2,-1 -1.4,-2.8 -3.1,-3.9 -2.9,-8.3 2,-0.9 2.5,-3.7 4.3,-3.9 0.7,1.6 1.4,2.2 2.2,3.3 -0.4,1.6 -0.6,2.1 0.1,4.1 1.2,3.4 2.7,0.9 5.6,1.8 0.9,0.3 0.7,1.1 1.8,1.3 0.9,-0.7 2.7,-2.3 3.3,-0.5 -0.7,0.8 -1.1,1.2 -0.6,2.1 2.9,-0.9 1.4,-1.7 4.8,-1 0.1,-0.2 0.2,-0.5 0.3,-0.7 -0.6,-0.7 -1.2,-1.3 -1.7,-2 0.1,-2 2.2,-5.2 3.6,-6 2.2,-0.6 2.4,0.2 3.9,-1.6 1.4,-0.2 2.1,-0.3 3.2,0 0.1,1 0.4,2.1 1,2.6 0.6,0.4 1.8,0.9 2.7,1.4 0.7,-0.4 1,-0.7 2.1,-0.9 1.3,1 3.7,3.4 5.5,3.5 0.9,-0.2 1.9,-0.3 2.8,-0.5 1.2,0.3 5.2,3.4 6.4,4.2 -0.2,0.6 -0.4,1.2 -0.7,1.8 1.6,-0.1 3.2,-0.1 4.7,-0.2 0.7,-0.4 0.7,-1.5 2.2,-1.4 1,0.1 2,0.2 2.9,0.4 1.2,-0.4 1.9,-1.7 3.8,-1.4 0.1,0.8 0,0.9 0.3,1.2 2.5,0.7 4.6,-2.4 6.8,-2.9 0.1,0.1 0.1,0.1 0.2,0.1 0.1,1.3 0.2,2.3 1,2.8 1.2,-0.9 4.6,-3.8 5.3,-0.9 0.4,-0.4 0.8,-0.8 1.2,-1.2 0.7,0.4 1.1,0.8 2.1,1 0.1,-0.8 0.2,-1 0.7,-1.4 1.3,0.2 2.1,0.1 2.7,1.2 0.8,-0.3 1.6,-0.5 2.5,-0.8 0.6,-2.2 1.4,-4 3,-5.4 2.8,-0.2 2.8,1.1 4.5,1.9 1.1,0.2 1.6,-0.1 2.1,-0.7 1.1,0.5 2.1,0.9 3.2,1.4 0,0.3 0.1,0.6 0.1,0.8 -0.3,0.3 -0.6,0.6 -0.9,0.9 0.3,0.6 0.6,1.3 0.9,1.9 -0.9,0.7 -4.7,14 -5.4,15.9 0.8,1 1.4,1.6 1.6,3.4 -1.1,0.6 -0.9,1.4 -1.1,2.7 0.6,0.5 0.9,0.7 1.2,1.7 -1.6,3.5 -1.7,8 -2.1,11.8 1.4,0.9 0.9,1.7 2,3 0.7,0.9 1.9,0.1 2.8,0.7 1.1,0.7 1,1.6 2.4,2.1 -0.1,2.6 1.1,3.7 2.6,5.5 0.2,0.3 1.2,4.1 1.4,4.8 2,4.2 -1.1,7.3 -0.8,11.1 z");
ctx.stroke(p);
ctx.fill(p);
ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
var getPt = function() {
  var x = Math.random() * 730,
    y = Math.random() * 390;
  if (!ctx.isPointInPath(p, x, y)) {
    return getPt();
  } else {
    return {
      "x": x,
      "y": y
    };
  }
};
for (j = 0; j < 700; j++) {
  var pt = getPt();
  ctx.fillRect(pt.x, pt.y, 1, 1);
};
```

```css
body {
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' height='390px' width='730px'></canvas>
```

Still, we can see lots of points drawn outside of the path. Please check.

**NOTE: `Path2D` is still not fully supported by every browser, if it breaks in your browser, please use latest Chrome for testing. For deployment, you may use [Canvas5 Polyfill](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill)**

Comment: Is your issue forming the map shape or rotating the images or something else?

Comment: For now I just want to have images wrapped inside the map shape, rest I will figure out

Comment: @RobertLongson I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: The coordinates passed to `isPointInPath()` should be in the path coordinate space.  You are passing canvas coords.  For a hint of what you need to do, try commenting out the `ctx.scale()` line.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau it seems the `ctx.scale()` is indeed causing trouble. Is there any solution for scaling path and still get job done? Provided SVG is what I currently have.

Comment: I have managed to scale the path data easily with Inkscape. I just needed to ungroup the path and voila, I got the scaled path data. Thanks to @PaulLeBeau for his answer and valuable comment.

Comment: The other solution I was hinting at was to scale the Canvas coordinates down by the same scale before passing them to `isPointInPath()`. :)

Comment: That would have been better. If you find any solution, it would be wise to update the answer, so other people may have that option too. Thanks for you hint btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas` has an [`isPointInPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) function.  One possible approach:

1. Create a Canvas
2. Define your map path on the Canvas
3. Place your images using something like the following.

   ```
   for each image to place:
      while (not foundpointinpath)
         x = random value between 0 & width
         y = random value between 0 & height)
         foundpointinpath = canvas.isPointInPath(path, x, y)
      draw image with random rotation at (x,y)
   ```

Comment: It looks promising, I will try and let you know the outcome. Thanks for your answer.